# How to center all the content in a div and keep distance between them the same

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to make it easier to center the content and make the distance between everything the same if the screen gets smaller. 
If the screen gets less height the content needs to get closer to each other but between every div needs to be the same distance.

HTML

```
<div id="our_culture"class="explor_us">
      <div class="colums">
    <div class="colum1" id="pic1">
      <div class="wilpe_logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/SVG_logo.svg/2000px-SVG_logo.svg.png" width="150px" height="100px" alt=""  /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text_holder">
        <p> Wilpe is an investment group specialized in supporting and developing growing businesses and brands. Wilpe believes in knowledge.
          <div class="button_two">
            <a class="button_text" href="#">Explore</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colum1" id="pic1">
      <div class="wilpe_logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/SVG_logo.svg/2000px-SVG_logo.svg.png" width="150px" height="100px" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text_holder">
        <p> Wilpe is an investment group specialized in supporting and developing growing businesses and brands. Wilpe believes in knowledge.
          <div class="button_two">
            <a class="button_text" href="#">Explore</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colum1" id="pic1">
      <div class="wilpe_logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/SVG_logo.svg/2000px-SVG_logo.svg.png" width="150px" height="100px" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text_holder">
        <p> Wilpe is an investment group specialized in supporting and developing growing businesses and brands. Wilpe believes in knowledge.
          <div class="button_two">
            <a class="button_text" href="/wilpe_import.html">Explore</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colum2" id="pic1">
      <div class="wilpe_logo">
        <a href="wilpetrade.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/SVG_logo.svg/2000px-SVG_logo.svg.png" width="150px" height="100px" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text_holder">
        <p> Wilpe is an investment group specialized in supporting and developing growing businesses and brands. Wilpe believes in knowledge.
          <div class="button_two">
            <a class="button_text" href="/wilpetrade.html">Explore</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colum2"id="pic1">
      <div class="wilpe_logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/SVG_logo.svg/2000px-SVG_logo.svg.png" width="150px" height="100px" alt=""  /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text_holder">
        <p> Wilpe is an investment group specialized in supporting and developing growing businesses and brands. Wilpe believes in knowledge.
          <div class="button_two">
            <a class="button_text" href="/wilpe_deal.html">Explore</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="photo_overlay_filter6"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.colum1{
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 55vh;
  float: right;
}
.colum2{
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 55vh;
  float: right;
}

.text_holder{
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 18%;
  z-index: 83;
  position: relative;
}
.wilpe_logo{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 83;
  position: relative;
}



#pic1{
  background-image:url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-triangles-background_yB0qTG6.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u60g7v89/

Comment: use flexbox if you don't need to support legacy browser

Comment: Thanks I'll try to figure out how i can get the space between the items the same with flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can now be accomplished with flexbox. This problem is exactly what the flex model was made for.

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.FlexBox{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.FlexItem{
  width:100%;
  background:#b00;
  border:5px solid #ddd;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="FlexBox">
 <div class="FlexItem">1</div>
 <div class="FlexItem">2</div>
 <div class="FlexItem">3</div>
 <div class="FlexItem">4</div>
 <div class="FlexItem">5</div>
</div>
```

To adjust the space between items simply set the width for each item to your desired value, in this case there are 5 elements so I want each to be 15%. (so the total width is less than 100%).

Then set `justify-content` property on flex container to either `spacce-around` or `space-between`.

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.FlexBox{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  justify-content:space-around; /*(space-between creates equal space with items left aligned)*/
}
.FlexItem{
  width:15%; /* (total items less than 100%) */
  background:#b00;
  border:5px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="FlexBox">
 <div class="FlexItem">1</div>
 <div class="FlexItem">2</div>
 <div class="FlexItem">3</div>
 <div class="FlexItem">4</div>
 <div class="FlexItem">5</div>
</div>
```

### Support

Flex is now supported in all major browsers.

*(Some setups can be buggy in i.e, but what's new? Just test before use.)*

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it but this doesn't fix the space between the items inside  right? Or is there also a function in flex for this?

Comment: see new notes in anser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option overflow scroll and make the scroll bar hidden I thinks this might solve your problem. The code you can use is :

```
.text_holder{
      overflow: scroll;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
```

These two parameters are to be added. As per my understanding this can solve your problem.